# Adding intent code in an if else statement

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the following intent code to add in an if else statement to redirect if login is successful after displaying the toast message under
**if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {** but I get an "Cannot resolve constructor error.

**Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);**

```
if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or Password incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

like this

```
if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or Password incorrect.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

2. I have an ImageView that is visible in Preview, but is not shown in the emulator. I have already clean/build the project and sync gradle files. What could be the issue?

Comment: Think you might want to change the title of your post

Comment: Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you are a new user, and this is your first question. Your question looks good! For more tips on writing great questions visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For more information about this site, or if you have any questions, just visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use this from an anonymous inner class? Then `this`refers to the inner class instead of the activity. Use this instead (like you did with the toasts):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your intent definition to this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
```

I look at how you call your toast and I infer that your lines of codes are in a inner class, so to refer to your activity context, you need to use `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with current activity and for better experience alwyas use a try and catch block for this kind of intent